# PHP - Login form - Show error message if login not valid

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I'm trying to use this login form (http://codepen.io/reidark/pen/uAmey) in my project, but I need a small help with one thing.

I need my script to show goodboy message in that green box under the login form when valid username and password is submited and then redirect to another page, when invalid credentials submited -> error message in the same box.

This is probably the most significant part of my code:

```
<?php

$login = ($_POST['login']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

$password = md5($password);

$login_def = "admin";
$password_def = "c4025c6fb582e687b11738a1fb416993";


?>

<form class="login" action="?page=login" method="POST">

  <fieldset>

    <legend class="legend">Login</legend>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login" required />
      <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
      <span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>

  </fieldset>

<?php
    if($login == $login_def && $password == $password_def){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $login;

        echo '
            <div class="feedback">
                Login success <br />
                redirecting...
            </div>
        ';
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php?page=projects'</script>";
}

    else{
        echo '
            <div class="feedback">
                Wrong username or password. <br />
                Please check the fields above.
            </div>
        ';      
    }
?>

</form>
```

But every time I submit wrong data, the page just reloads and no message (↑feedback) is shown. Could you tell me, please, where I made a mistake? Thank you very much for it.

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql infection. You should escape all user input

Comment: @SuperDJ sql what?, there is no sql in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$login = ($_POST['login']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$password = md5($password);
$login_def = "admin";
$password_def = "c4025c6fb582e687b11738a1fb416993";
?>
<form class="login" action="?page=login" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="legend">Login</legend>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login" required />
            <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
            <span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($login == $login_def && $password == $password_def) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $login;
            echo '<div class="feedback">Login success <br />redirecting...</div>';
            echo "<script>window.location='index.php?page=projects'</script>";
        } else {
            echo '<div class="feedback">Wrong username or password. <br />Please check the fields above.</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

The above code is working fine in my localhost.